# Throttling connections to ASMX Web Service from the client side

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asmx

I'm calling an asmx service repeatedly using the Async methods and am getting this error

```
The HTTP request to 'https://example.com/WebService.asmx' has exceeded the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
```

Is there any easy way that I can throttle my calls so that I don't overload the server and therefore my requests will return in time (assuming that's the problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do it if you're using a Web Reference.

In fact, I don't think there's a way to do it with a Service Reference either.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have just had a crazy thought involving TryInvokeMember and a queue.